# BASH: Finding maximum value in a particular CSV column

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have a CSV file `million_songs_metadata_and_sales.csv` having the following schema.

```
track_id    
sales_date  
sales_count
title
song_id 
release 
artist_id   
artist_mbid 
artist_name 
duration    
artist_familiarity  
artist_hotttnesss
year
```

Sample data:

```
TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,79,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001
```

I need to write a query in BASH to find the artist_name with maximum sales using the file `million_songs_metadata_and_sales.csv`.

I have written the following script but it fails to give me the correct data:

```
awk 'max=="" || $3 > max {max=$3} END{ print $9}' FS="," million_songs_metadata_and_sales.csv
```

Any work around to this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$N` can be used only when `awk` is processing a line.

```
$ cat file.csv
TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,77,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium 1,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001
TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,79,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001
TRZZZZZ12903D05E3A,2014-06-19,78,Infra Stellar,SOZPUEF12AF72A9F2A,Archives Vol. 2,ARBG8621187FB54842,4279aba0-1bde-40a9-8fb2-c63d165dc554,Delerium 2,495.22893,0.69652442519,0.498471038842,2001
$ awk 'BEGIN { max=0 } $3 > max { max=$3; name=$9 } END { print name }' FS="," file.csv
Delerium
$
```

Answer (score 4):

The

```
cut -d, -f3,9 < data.csv | sort -nr | head -1
```

will do it.

*And will fail immediately if some columns containing a comma.*  For correct CSV parsing you need to use some cvs-parsing library.